# issues with mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, syntax-error

I have issues with `$mysqli->prepare` with the following code:

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `Orders` (OrderID,IP.Email.File,Cat,Price,Discount,Size,Scaleby,Emailed,Downloaded,Payment,DateTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Current code:

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `Orders` (OrderID,IP,Email,File,Cat,Price,Discount,Size,Scaleby,Emailed,Downloaded,Payment,DateTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Error message:

> Prepare failed: (1136) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

code used to make table:

```
if ($mysqli->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Orders` (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
OrderID CHAR(40),
IP CHAR(40),
Email VARCHAR(254),
File VARCHAR(30),
Cat VARCHAR(30),
Price DEC(5,2),
Discount DEC(3,2),
Size VARCHAR(30),
Scaleby DEC(3,2),
Emailed BOOL,
Downloaded BOOL,
Payment VARCHAR(30),
DateTime DATETIME)') === False){
printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

**I have** tried removing `(...)` from `INSERT INTO...` in an attempt to fix the error but that did not work. **I also** tried simplifying it to 3 `?` marks but it still did not work.

**The `?` marks are placeholders in a prepared statement**

Comment: You are separating field names `IP`, `Email` and `File` with dots instead of commas.

Comment: If you **read** the error message "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" - then you'll get what it means.

Comment: @zerkms LOL, I did but it's pretty cryptic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the number of columns in the table, it's that there's a typo in the `insert` statement.  You've got "IP.Email.File" instead of "IP,Email,File", so the DB engine thinks you have a different number of columns than literals specified in the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO `Orders`

-- 11 columns here, because "IP.Email.File" parses as one column
(OrderID,IP.Email.File,Cat,Price,Discount,Size,Scaleby,Emailed,Downloaded,Payment,DateTime) 

-- 13 values here
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: That is one half of the problem but it still does not work
`Prepare failed: (1136) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: @linuxrules94 if the counts really are the same, I don't really know what else it could be.  Can you maybe add your question and post the code you're using now?

Comment: @linuxrules94 now there are 14 question marks, 13 columns named

Comment: Thank YOU so much I was about to pull my hair out over this lol

Comment: @linuxrules94 no prob -- sometimes you've just been staring at something for so long it becomes a blur